# JPanel doesnt show components after the second button click

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, jtextpane

I want to put a JTextPane component in a JPanel with a GridBagLayout when I click on button.
My code works fine for the first button click, But after, the next components are not displayed.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class RefreshPanel {

private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
private JTextPane [] textPane;// = new JTextPane[1];
private JScrollPane scrollbar;
private ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
private JButton newItem = new JButton("new");
private int counter=0;
private GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();

RefreshPanel() {

    scrollbar = new JScrollPane(panel);

    panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    panel.setLayout(gbl);                       

    addButtonListener();        

    createFrame();
} //constructor

public void addButtonListener() {
    newItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            arrayList.add("data");
            textPane = generateTextPane(arrayList.size(), arrayList);
            System.out.println(textPane.length);
            for(int i=0;i<textPane.length;i++) {
                System.out.println(textPane[i].getText());
                addComponent(panel, gbl, textPane[i], 0, counter, 1, 1,1,1);
                panel.revalidate();
            }       
        }
    });
}

private JTextPane[] generateTextPane(int arraySize, ArrayList arrayList) {
    JTextPane [] textPane = new JTextPane[arraySize];
    for(int i=0;i<textPane.length;i++) {
        textPane[i]=new JTextPane();    
        textPane[i].setText((String) arrayList.get(i));
    }
    return textPane;
}

public void addComponent(Container cont, 
         GridBagLayout gbl, 
         Component c,
         int x, int y,
         int width, int height,
         double weightx, double weighty) {

    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc.gridx = x; gbc.gridy = y;
    gbc.gridwidth = width; gbc.gridheight = height;
    gbc.weightx = weightx; gbc.weighty = weighty;
    gbl.setConstraints( c, gbc );
    cont.add( c );
}
public void createFrame() {
    //frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.add(scrollbar, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(newItem, BorderLayout.EAST);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(300,300));
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
public static void main(String [] args) {
    new RefreshPanel();
}       
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the code that's in your constructor should be called from the Swing Event Dispatch Thread.  Not sure if it's completely relevant, but it's what I'd try.  Check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeAndWait%28java.lang.Runnable%29

Comment: And if you started reading the Oracle Tutorials, you should continue reading [How to use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) There you'll find a nice example how to use the GBC. You have to change your GridBagConstraints, up to now you add every new `JTextPane` with the same Constraints.

Comment: @Patrick: you are right! I really forgot to change the -grid-bagconstraints **addComponent(panel, gbl, textPane[i], 0, i, 1, 1, 1, 1);**instead of **addComponent(panel, gbl, textPane[i], 0, counter, 1, 1, 1, 1);**

Comment: @Patrick One of you should post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Patrick: you are right! I really forgot to change the gridbagconstraints

```
addComponent(panel, gbl, textPane[i], 0, i, 1, 1, 1, 1);
```

instead of

```
addComponent(panel, gbl, textPane[i], 0, counter, 1, 1, 1, 1);
```